# CSS class dynamicaly added based on JSON value in React

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a JSON value based on percentage. Is there a way add different CSS classes based on it?

E.g. If is 10 to 20% then red. If is 20-30 then orange, till 100%.

Comment: I would suggest you use Styled-Components library.
Lets you define css-modules that take properties.

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe provide some more information about the JSON or cases (ranges of percentage) in which you need to apply a class?

I see it like that: you have a few classes that are already defined with various names, and for example you have a JSON array that's mapped in JSX — in each entry of the array you have some percentage value according to which you can apply a class. For example:

```js
const json = {
  objects: [
    {
      id: 1,
      label: 'Foo',
      percentage: 37,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      label: 'Bar',
      percentage: 68
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      label: 'Biz',
      percentage: 12,
    }
  ]
}

const getClassname = (percentage) => {
  if (percentage > 0 && percentage <= 33) {
    return 'red'
  } else if (percentage > 33 && percentage <= 66) {
    return 'yellow'
  } else if (percentage > 66 && percentage <= 100) {
    return 'green'
  }
}

const Component = ({label, percentage}) => {
  return (
    <div className={getClassname(percentage)}>{label}</div>
  )
}

const List = ({list}) => {
 return {
  list.map(entry => (
    <Component
      key={entry.id}
      label={entry.label}
      percentage={entry.percentage}
     />
    )
 }
}

const App = () => {
 return (<List list={json.objects}/>)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a json with an array of item inside, you could do smething like this :

```
const json = [
  {
    percent: 10
  },
  {
    percent: 35
  },
  {
    percent: 78
  }
];

let myClass = "class1";

const setClass = () => {
  json.forEach(item => {
    if(item.percent >=10 && item.percent <= 35) myClass = 'class2';
    if(item.percent > 35 && item.percent <= 78) myClass = 'class3';
  })
}
```

And then set your class as follow :

`<input type="text" value="defaultValue" className={myClass} />`

Answer (score 0):

```
fetchFunction = ()=> { 
let jsonValueList=parseInt(jsonData);
   this.setState({jsonValue: jsonValueList}); }  

_.map(this.state.jsonValue, (item, index) => { 

    <span key={index} className={ (item <= 100 && item >= 90) ? "colorBlack" : (item < 90 && item >= 80) ? "colorGreen" : "..."}></span>})
```

Comment: Most simple and works without extra coding! Assuming you have already mapped your JSON. Thanks. I'll try to test the other answers too, to be fair.